# Intellisense for Objective-J?

Tags: intellisense, cappuccino, objective-j

My editor of choice for Objective-J Cappuccino development right now is Sublime Text 2. Unfortunately I haven't had any luck finding an Objective-J intellisense autocomplete plugin. It seems it should be doable, since Objective-J does have (optional/pluggable) types. So I think a plugin could definitely parse the code to find the expected type of the object you're trying to autocomplete on, and then look up its method list. Does anyone know of any other editors that support intellisense for Objective-J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They is only one intellisense plugin for vim available. 
You can find a little example video on youtube : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJrOcHxq6vc

Plugin:
https://github.com/nanki/vim-objj

Answer (score 0):

For Sublime Text 2 you can try https://github.com/aparajita/Cappuccino-Sublime, although it is not that "intelli" as vim plugin.

After installing you should be able to get autocompletion using `Ctrl+Space`.